# Плавающая кнопка на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css

[На видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh-p0IK2K1w) представлено как работает кнопка на [сайте](http://project2980996.tilda.ws/page13963266.html). Как сделать плавную анимацию ее движения, то есть вверх-вниз? (со скроллом я разобрался)

Например [стрелочка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHzEp.png)

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHzEp.png" alt="" height="20" class="scroll-down">

<style>
    .scroll-down {
        position: relative;
        animation: bounce 0.4s infinite;
    }
</style>
```

Насколько я понимаю нужно использовать keyframes, которые есть в CSS

```
@keyframes bounce {
  0 {
    top: 0;
  }
  50% {
    top: 2.5px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 5px;
  }
}
```

К моему глубокому сожалению, это работает, но не так как там, [очень коряво](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xm0wf4tgiaiwym3/FJBNj5ecwU.mp4?dl=0).
Как добиться плавности движения стрелочки?

Comment: Подробности. Мы жаждем подробностей. Движения куда, зачем? Что Вы уже сделали? Приведите код прямо в вопросе. Объясните **подробнее**, что именно Вы хотите видеть в результате, иначе Ваш вопрос заминусуют и Вы останетесь без ответа. И уберите ссылки. Код лучше.

Comment: @V-Mor, сделано

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть библиотека эффектов анимации для кнопок на css

http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/

Посмотрите, что вам надо, скачайте и можете или использовать саму библиотеку, подключая необходимые классы к объектам, которые хотите анимировать

Или посмотрите внутрь hover.css (только не hover.min.css) и возьмёте код оттуда для конкретной анимации и можете его покрутить под свои нужды

Comment: Спасибо большое